# SQL Developer format like Toad's Quest Parser version 5

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, code-formatting, toad

I use version control and some of my team use Toad, others use SQL Developer.  Is there someway to align the two formats?

The reason being that when you compare the versions most of the changes are due to formatting.

In Toad, you use Ctrl + Shift + F

In SQL Developer, you use Ctrl + F7

In SQL Developer it has some other formatting, but nothing for Toad which uses QP5 (Quest Parser Version 5)

[image]

Comment: You can configure how SQL Developer formats code (Tools->Preferences->Code Editor->Format), and I imagine Toad has something similar. Is there something in there you cannot make work the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can change how SQL Developer formats your code; from the menu go to:

Tools->Preferences->Code Editor->Format.

[image]

Go into Advanced Formatting to configure alignment, line breaks. whitespace etc.

Toad presumably [has similar options](http://documents.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/12.1/guide-to-using-toad-for-oracle/chapter-1-getting-started/execute-and-manage-code/work-with-code/format-code). You just need to set them up the same, which may need a bit of trial and error to get right.

Comment: I was aware of that option, however I was hoping there was some formatting I could just import.